# Maven in TeamCity: "Unable to locate the Javac Compiler..."

Tags: java, maven, teamcity

I'm trying to build a Maven project in TeamCity. When I run the build, I get the following error:[14:43:19][Compiler] Compilation failure

```
Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:  
  C:\BuildAgent\jre\..\lib\tools.jar 
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

Is this a Maven issue or a TeamCity issue?

Do I have to set JAVA_HOME on the build agent machine? What if in the future I end up with different builds requiring different version of the JDK?

Thanks in advance,
urig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the latest version of TeamCity, here's the link on [how TeamCity finds JDK](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Maven#Maven-JavaParameters).

I usually have `JAVA_HOME` env variable set. If you end up with different builds requiring different version of JDK, you can easily override path to JDK in build step configuration ("JDK home path" option).

Answer (score 1):

Well this is more of Maven than TeamCity. 
Faced this problem recently and the best way to get around this is to set the JAVA_HOME variable, which should point to the JDK installed as highlighted by the error message. 
Additionally, you can also make sure that the PATH on your machine is modified to include %JAVA_HOME%/bin. 
Post environment variables been set - re-start the TeamCity Build Agent service, if you are on Windows.